# Matlab plot marker label (NodeLabel) property

Tags: matlab, marker, user-defined

Is there any way to access and set plot marker property in Matlab?

In some case especially when user defined `Marker` is used (like the image below), it is necessary to set `NodeLabel`'s position, font and color, to make it distinct in the figure.

[image]

```
g_obj = graph(sources, targets);
gp = plot(g_obj);
```

`gp` is a Matlab `GraphPlot` object and even though `gp.NodeLabel` is located in above layer, but has visual interference with user-defined markers' black lines and for example *AL1*, *NAL1* and *S6R2* are not readable.

Is there any way to set the Marker's font and position, using the `gp` itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this [solution](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/267170-how-can-i-control-node-label-font-size-of-a-graph-or-digraph-object) which gives some flexibility, just copied the position and labels then used text instead of NodeLabel with more flexibility in color, font and etc.

```
%%---
gp = plot(graph_object,'Layout','layered');
labels = gp.NodeLabel;
gp.NodeLabel = [];
gp.LineStyle = 'none'; gp.Marker = 'none';

for i=1:length(labels)
    text(gp.XData(i)+2, gp.YData(i)-5,labels(i),...
       'fontsize', 8,'FontName', 'Arial', 'Color',[0 0.25 0],...
       'FontWeight', 'bold');
end
```

[image]